# How to enable horizontal scroll in Flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-web

I normal flat list in react native and I have react native web that renders the mobile component in web

I am hiding the scrollbar with the prop `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}`,

The scrolling works fine and as expected in mobile, but in the web the scrolling is completely halted as it does not allow dragging to scroll like mobile.

```
  <FlatList
            horizontal={true}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Button
                   .... />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(....}
            data={data} />
```

Is there any way to enable scroll behavior on the web like on mobile?

If not just have a scrollbar that only pops up when the section

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}`

Use `overflow: hidden` to the root view.

Comment: Tried that but doesnot seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In react-native-webview library there is a prop named as scrollEnabled set it to true.

Comment: Its not on webview, its react native for web so its completely like the web version